Primevue Multiselect field to autogrow to see all selected options
I am using Primevue Multiselect component and currently it truncates the items that were selected, which makes it a bad usability. No idea how to make it increase in height to see all options.
The code:
<div class="flex flex-wrap items-center gap-2 mb-4"> <label for="grapes" class="font-semibold w-20">Grapes</label> <MultiSelect  v-model="selected.grapes" display="chip" :options="store.grapes"  optionLabel="name"  optionValue="id"  filter  class="ml-2 w-full md:w-[13.4rem]"  /> <Button type="button" icon="pi pi-plus" size="small" @click="dialog_visible = true" /> </div> 
The screenshot:
enter image description here
I tried increasing the height and changing the overflow but nothing worked so far.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

apologies for not being too clear. Currently, the field showing the selected items does not increase in size so the chips are truncated, the user cannot see the items he selected. I tried to show it in the screenshot. What I want is for the field to expand in size to show all chips of the selected items to the user without needing to go back to the dropdown menu and correct the selection if the mistake was made. Hope that makes sence
